# AS3 - Getting a stream connection ip

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, ip

I need to have debugging/logging information for a flash video player.

I need to display the client ip, along with the server ip of the stream... can this be done?

example stream: (actually it's a manifest that, upon load, retrieves the stream)
http://multiplatform-f.akamaihd.net/z/multi/april11/hdworld/hdworld_,512x288_450_b,640x360_700_b,768x432_1000_b,1024x576_1400_m,1280x720_1900_m,1280x720_2500_m,1280x720_3500_m,.mp4.csmil/manifest.f4m

Techs available to me:  Javascript, AS3 FLASH.
basically a "whatsmyip" and a reverse ip lookup through flash/javascript.... possible without server side scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get client IP with JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getip(data){
      alert(data.ip);
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jsonip.appspot.com/?callback=getip">
</script>
```

Or with php:

```
<?php
    echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
?>
```

Get server IP only with server side script, like php:

```
<?php
$ip = gethostbyname('www.example.com');

echo $ip;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

So how do sites like: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/web-sites-on-web-server/  
pull the server ip of a url?  


Are there no properties of a NetConnection class or NetStream class, etc. that would hold the ip of the server it tries to connect to?

Comment: No native methods, NetConnection works with domain name or ip but doesn't make convert domain to ip address.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3422604) online, I don't know if it would help you. Hope it does.